# Recursive Fibonacci with Generic delegates

Tags: c#, recursion, generics, fibonacci-sequence

Here is a fast recursive Fibonacci-like `for` loop. How can it be more readable, and is it possible remove `TArg`s?

```
public static class Fibonacci
{
    public static BigInteger Calculate(BigInteger number)
    {
        var fibo = AnonRecursiveFiboFunc<BigInteger>(
            func => (step, fibo1, fibo2) => step == number
            ? fibo2
            : func(++step, fibo1 + fibo2, fibo1));
        return fibo(0, 1, 0);
    }

    delegate Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4>
        Recursive<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4>(
        Recursive<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4> r);

    private static Func<TArg, TArg, TArg, TArg> 
        AnonRecursiveFiboFunc<TArg>(Func<Func<TArg, TArg, TArg, TArg>,
                                         Func<TArg, TArg, TArg, TArg>> function)
    {
        Recursive<TArg, TArg, TArg, TArg> recursive = 
            rec => (step, fibo1, fibo2) => 
                function(rec(rec))(step, fibo1, fibo2);
        return recursive(recursive);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you are using a delegate instead of using an actual function.  It seems to me like this is taking the scenic route instead of the interstate.

Comment: i use delegate because i want try it with delegates :) but i dont like multiple TArg's. 
And i know this is not the best way. I test what can i do with delegates.

Comment: I always get confused by this kind of recursion. Is this supposed to be [the Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator)?

Answer (score 5):

1. I like to say `T1` `T2` instead of `TArg1`, it just makes it more clear to me what is going on. Your code would look more like this.

   ```
   delegate Func<T1, T2, T3, T4> Recursive<T1, T2, T3, T4>( Recursive<T1, T2, T3, T4> r);

   private static Func<T, T, T, T> AnonRecursiveFiboFunc<T>(Func<Func<T, T, T, T>, Func<T, T, T, T>> function)
   {
       Recursive<T, T, T, T> recursive = rec => (step, fibo1, fibo2) => function(rec(rec))(step, fibo1, fibo2);
       return recursive(recursive);
   }
   ```

Other than that... this code seems pretty solid, except for the crazy lack of immediate readability :D and like mentioned in the comments the fact that you are using delegates at all here.

Answer (score 5):

The opposite of BenVlodgi's answer: i.e. `AnonRecursiveFiboFunc<TArg>` has only one template parameter, therefore all the template arguments passed to `Recursive<TArg, TArg, TArg, TArg> recursive` are the same, therefore there only needs to be one of them.

You can rewrite the code as:

```
    delegate Func<T, T, T, T> Recursive<T>(Recursive<T> r);

    private static Func<TArg, TArg, TArg, TArg>
        AnonRecursiveFiboFunc<TArg>(Func<Func<TArg, TArg, TArg, TArg>,
                                         Func<TArg, TArg, TArg, TArg>> function)
    {
        Recursive<TArg> recursive =
            rec => (step, fibo1, fibo2) =>
                function(rec(rec))(step, fibo1, fibo2);
        return recursive(recursive);
    }
```

Given that all the arguments passed to Func are the same, you can reduce it further by defining your own delegate (which I named Function3) as follows:

```
    delegate T Function3<T>(T arg1, T arg2, T arg3);

    delegate Function3<T> Recursive<T>(Recursive<T> r);

    private static Function3<TArg>
        AnonRecursiveFiboFunc<TArg>(Func<Function3<TArg>,
                                         Function3<TArg>> function)
    {
        Recursive<TArg> recursive =
            rec => (step, fibo1, fibo2) =>
                function(rec(rec))(step, fibo1, fibo2);
        return recursive(recursive);
    }
```

Comment: I almost suggested this, but because he was using BigInteger for one type and not for the others, I didn't. Although I guess 3 of them could have indeed been collapsed.... unless I read it wrong o_O

Comment: Ok i see it now :)

Comment: @BenVlodgi He wasn't using BigInteger for one type and not for the others: BigInteger is the only type because there is only one type, i.e. the type that's passed to the `AnonRecursiveFiboFunc<TArg>` method, which only has one template parameter. I downvoted your answer because your suggestion made that even less clear, not "more clear" as you said.

Comment: @ChrisW The only thing I suggested was that he rename his T arguments

Comment: I already liked @ChrisW's answer. It's good option with yours.

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you liked using delegates, and you wanted to see what you could do with them. But I think its good to recognize when you don't need to make your own.

Here is a simpler refactored version of your code. It does not use your `A non recursive function` delegate. Also, technically what you were doing before was recursion still.

```
public static BigInteger Calculate(BigInteger number)
{
    Func<BigInteger, BigInteger, BigInteger, BigInteger> fibo = null;
    fibo = ((step, fibo1, fibo2) => (step == number) ? fibo2 : fibo(++step, fibo1 + fibo2, fibo1));
    return fibo(0, 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: i use another method because i dont like `= null;`.

Comment: @VictorTomaili I didn't like it either... but that is a bit over-kill :D

Comment: `Func<> fibo = null;` is required to provide an instantiation, prior to the definition; somewhat like a forward reference.